# Star-autonomous categories are linearly distributive categories with negation?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, duality-theorems, monoidal-categories, diagram-chasing

**1.Context**
On page 28 of  *[Weakly distributive categories](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/linear/Cockett-Seely-WDC-Durham1991-corrected.pdf)* Cockett and Seely are trying to prove the following statement:

> The notions of symmetric weakly distributive categories with negation and star-autonomous categories coincide.

When dealing with the direction that any star-autonomous category carries a linear distributive structure, they write:

> It is a straightforward verification to check that star-autonomous categories are weakly distributive, though the diagrams can be pretty horrid. We shall just indicate how the weak distribution $\delta_L^{L}$ is obtained, leaving the rest to the faith of the reader.

Since I do not have much faith, I tried to verify that statement myself.

**2. Definition**
I am working with the following definition of star-autonomous category.

Let $(C, \otimes,  I, a, l,r)$ be a symmetric monoidal category.
A *star-autonomous structure* on the monoidal category $C$ consists of an adjoint equivalence $D \dashv D’: C^{op} \xrightarrow{\sim} C$ together with bijections $\phi_{X,Y,Z}: Hom_C(X \otimes Y,DZ) \xrightarrow{\sim} Hom_C(X, D(Y \otimes Z))$ natural in $X,Y,Z$.

**3. Progress**
After having (supposedly) derived left distributor and right distributor (by writing them as a composition of morphisms involving $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ as well as the application of functors $D$ and $D’$), I am now unsuccesfully trying to verify that the necessary diagrams given by Cockett and Seely commute.

**4. Question**

- Is the proof of the claim that any star-autonomous category carries a linear distributive structure given in greater detail somewhere in the literature?

Comment: Apparently, a more detailed proof can be found in the third chapter of *K. Došen, Z. Petrić, Proof-Net Categories, 2005*.